# MAGENTO - Display sub-category products in root category

Tags: magento, categories

i havent been able to find the answer for this anywhere but i cant seen to display any of the products on the root categories page from its sub category members. When i click the category from the top navigation i get the sub categories on the left and on the right (main content) “There are no products matching the selection”. Each sub-cat. shows its products though.

In Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories each category shows the number of products i.e (4) however its root category displays (0).

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

---

**Solution**

Go to Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories -> "Select Category" -> Display Settings -> Is Anchor = "Yes"

Then:

Admin -> System -> Index Management -> "Select All" -> "Reindex data" -> "Submit"

Thanks for everyones comments

Comment: Thanks, Reindex Works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure you set "Is anchor" to "Yes" for your root category.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not show products from child categories in parent categories, as the poster requested.

Comment: @zschuessler thats right, still no products display - infact with anchor set to "yes" takes away the sub cat. on the left column

Comment: however @rpSetzer the root cat now displays correct number of products in (0) e.g. (28).

Comment: @rpSetzer - take that back :) needed to reindex in Admin -> System - Index Management and reindex them all. Thanks

Comment: @Stevanicus are you still looking for a solution to show products? I was in the middle of putting code together for you.

Comment: @zschuessler - thanks for that! rpSetzer's steps worked tho. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 7):

Set anchor as YES and then reindex categories in index management.

Answer (score 2):

Every category has associated products.
Just associate these products into the higher-level category too.
They will show up on frontend in that category.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but the "Category Products" tab of the root cat. doesnt display any products.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="category-grid-new">
    <?php $_columnCount; ?>
        <ul>
            <?php if($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0):?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>">
                        <div class="category-img"><img src="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl() ?>" alt="" width="100px" height="100px"/></div>
                        <div class="category-data"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName()) ?></div>
                    </a>
                </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First identify the attribute id of the is_anchor attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_anchor';
```

we Get attribute id 51 in my database. Now run the following query

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 1 where attribute_id = 51;
```

replace 51 with your own attribute id. And just rebuild these indexes